# How to put space between flows, I'm using shoes gui toolkit

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

I'm a new programmer, and only know ruby programming language. I was asked to make an interactive interface but am still struggling with the layout. This is most of it but for aesthetic reasons want to add space between the boxes inside the flow with the blue border.

here is my code so far

```
Shoes.app(title: "bullying app", width: 1250, height: 840) do
 #header
    flow width: 1.0, height: 0.3 do
    title 'bullying app'
    background rgb(119,136,153)
    border pink
    end

    #dropdown menu with which child
    stack margin: 20 do
    para 'which child'
    list_box items: ["child 1", "child 2", "child 3"]
    end


    # tabs buttons
    flow margin_left: 800 do
    button 'summary'
    button 'web'
    button 'time'
    button 'social media'
    button 'alerts'
    border red
    end

flow margin: 10
 flow width: 1.0, height: 0.4 do
 border blue

 #first square "most recent sites"
 flow width: 0.2, height: 0.99 do
 flow margin_left: 400   
 background white
 border darkorange,strokewidth:2
 para strong "most recent websites visited" 
 stack margin:10 do
 para "1. facebook.com"
 para "2. google.com"
 para "3. twitter.com"
 para "4. wikepedia.com"
 para "5. mnps.black.board.com"
 para "6. pinterest.com"
 end
 end


 flow width:0.5, height: 0.99 do
 border green
 flow  width: 1.0, height:0.6 do
 border yellow 

 flow width: 0.5, height: 0.99 do
 background white
 border darkorange,strokewidth: 2
 para strong  "time"  
 end

 flow width: 0.5, height: 0.99 do
 background white
 border darkorange, strokewidth:2
 para strong "social media:recent"
 end
 end

 flow width: 1.0, height: 0.4 do
 background white
 para strong 'recent searches'
 border purple
 end
 end
flow width: 0.2, height:0.99 do
 background white
 border darkorange
 para strong 'alerts'
 end
end
end
```

I know it's a bit messy, sorry.
Any and all help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure where you want to put the space, but in general `margin` is probably what you are looking for. E.g. adding `margin_left: 10` or something like that to the flows where you want to have some further spacing. There are margin_left, margin_top, margin_right and margin_bottom.

Other options include adding an empty flow/stack to give the other flows some space.

I added some margin_lefts in your code and reformatted it, here you go:

```
Shoes.app(title: "bullying app", width: 1250, height: 840) do
  #header
  flow width: 1.0, height: 0.3 do
    title 'bullying app'
    background rgb(119,136,153)
    border pink
  end

  #dropdown menu with which child
  stack margin: 20 do
    para 'which child'
    list_box items: ["child 1", "child 2", "child 3"]
  end


  # tabs buttons
  flow margin_left: 800 do
    button 'summary'
    button 'web'
    button 'time'
    button 'social media'
    button 'alerts'
    border red
  end

  flow margin: 10
  flow width: 1.0, height: 0.4 do
    border blue

    #first square "most recent sites"
    flow width: 0.2, height: 0.99 do
      flow margin_left: 400
      background white
      border darkorange,strokewidth:2
      para strong "most recent websites visited"
      stack margin:10 do
        para "1. facebook.com"
        para "2. google.com"
        para "3. twitter.com"
        para "4. wikepedia.com"
        para "5. mnps.black.board.com"
        para "6. pinterest.com"
      end
    end


    flow width:0.5, height: 0.99 do
      border green
      flow  width: 1.0, height:0.6 do
        border yellow

        flow width: 0.5, height: 0.99, margin_left: 10 do
          background white
          border darkorange,strokewidth: 2
          para strong  "time"
        end

        flow width: 0.5, height: 0.99, margin_left: 10 do
          background white
          border darkorange, strokewidth:2
          para strong "social media:recent"
        end
      end

      flow width: 1.0, height: 0.4 do
        background white
        para strong 'recent searches'
        border purple
      end
    end
    flow width: 0.2, height:0.99, margin_left: 10 do
      background white
      border darkorange
      para strong 'alerts'
    end
  end
end
```

Shoes on!